# How would I incorporate a class into this random generator?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'd like to add the option to include a Integer and Double class into my project and would like some help since I'm stuck.

header:

```
#ifndef RANDOM
#define RANDOM

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Double.h"

const int Int_b = 250;//these are for main
const int Int_s = 225;

class Random
{
private:
    std::vector<double> vectx;
    double _min, _max;
    int currIndex;
    void fillVect(double min, double max);
    //void fillVect(Double min, Double max);
    void shuffle();

public:
    Random();
    Random(double min, double max);
    //Random(Double min, Double max);
    Random(int seed);
    int nextInt();
    //Integer nextInteger();
    double nextDbl();
    //Double nextDouble();
    //void setRange(Double min, Double max);
    void setRange(double min, double max);
};
#endif
```

The commented codes are the ones I'd like to add

cpp:

```
#include "Random.h"
#include "Double.h"
using namespace std;
Random::Random() {
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));
    fillVect(0.0, RAND_MAX);
}
Random::Random(double min, double max) {
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));
    fillVect(min, max);
}
/*Random::Random(Double min, Double max)
{
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));
    fillVect(min, max);
}*/
Random::Random(int seed) {
    srand(seed);
    fillVect(0.0, RAND_MAX);
}
void Random::fillVect(double min, double max) {
    vectx.clear();
    currIndex = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Int_b; ++i)
    {
        double r = (((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX * (max - min)) + min);
        vectx.push_back(r);
    }
    shuffle();
}
/*void Random::fillVect(Double min, Double max) {
    vectx.clear();
    currIndex = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Int_b; ++i)
    {
        Double r = (((Double)rand() / (Double)RAND_MAX * (max - min)) + min);
        vectx.push_back(r);
    }
    shuffle();
}*/
void Random::shuffle() {
    random_shuffle(vectx.begin(), vectx.end());
}
int Random::nextInt() {
    if (currIndex > Int_s)
    {
        currIndex = 0;
        shuffle();
    }
    return (int)vectx[currIndex++];
}
double Random::nextDbl() {
    if (currIndex > Int_s)
    {
        currIndex = 0;
        shuffle();
    }
    return vectx[currIndex++];
}
void Random::setRange(double min, double max) {
    vectx.clear();
    fillVect(min, max);
}
```

This was my attempt but I cant wrap my head around it.

This is my Double class.

```
class Double
{
private:
    double data;
public:
    Double();
    Double(double d);
    Double(const Double &d);
    Double(const Integer &i);
    void equals(double d);
    Double add(const Double &d);
    Double sub(const Double &d);
    Double mul(const Double &d);
    Double div(const Double &d);
    Double add(double d);
    Double sub(double d);
    Double mul(double d);
    Double div(double d);
    double toDouble() const;
    Double operator + (const Double &d);
    Double operator - (const Double &d);
    Double operator * (const Double &d);
    Double operator / (const Double &d);
    Double operator = (const Double &d);
    Double operator = (double d);
    bool operator == (const Double &d);
    bool operator == (double d);
    bool operator != (const Double &d);
    bool operator != (double d);
};
```

Comment: The classes are already made I'm just trying to plug them in.

Comment: `srand(unsigned(time(0)));` in a constructor is a bad idea. Every time you create a new instance of the class you will reseed the RNG for all instances of the class and anyone else in the program using `rand`. Could lead to interesting bugs. `srand` should be called once and only once, probably early in `main`.

Comment: Need to see the `Double` class to make any meaningful recommendations.

Comment: What is the problem you encountered? Did you see an error? Or were you unsatisfied with the result? Which one and how?

Comment: I haven't encountered a problem because I don't even know where to start. Do I just make a carbon copy of the function without the classes and then just replace them with the class?

Comment: `Random::Random(Double min, Double max)`
`{`
 `srand(unsigned(time(0)));`
 `fillVect(min, max);`
`}` This is what I would imagine it would look like but this doesn't work.

Comment: Daniz, you say you haven't encountered a problem, but the thing you imagine does not work. You are contradicting yourself. You need to tell us how is it not working?

Comment: Suggestion: Only have one `Random::Random` and `Random::fillVect`, the `double` one. `std::vector<double> vectx;` can't hold anything but `double`s, so why screw around trying to fit in different data types? Unless you are going to make a templated class, you can't, so just move on and implement `Double nextDouble();` to use the `double` from `vectx` to construct and return a `Double`.

Comment: You said if there was a problem so I went out and created one by attempting it. I tried replacing the primitive double's, min and max, in the argument with Double min and max. I'd like to know how to fix this so that the class can work in this seperate function `Random(Double min, Double max)`

Comment: Why the hell make a Double class?

Comment: @RegisPortalez, ask the Java guys, they have double as primitive type and Double as a class as well.

Comment: @regis portalez, idk its just in the assignment description

Comment: daniz11529 I recommend taking a breather and reminding yourself that `Double` is not `double`. You cannot assign `Double` to `double` You cannot cast `Double` to `double` and expect any more success than you get from casting an apple into an orange. You can convert `double` into `Double` because `Double` has a rule to allow this, but not the reverse.

Comment: @user4581301, thanks for the advice, i've been staring at this assignment all day and its all becoming a blur at this point.

Comment: You can convert your Random class into a template like this: `template<class myDouble> class Random{...};`. Then you can put you Double class as a parameter: `Random<Double> my_rnd_obj;`. Do you mean something like this?

Comment: The whole point of a random "class" is that you can have separate sequences with their own seeds. if you create several of them, however, you need to be careful that the seeds are independent.

Comment: my objective with `Random(Double min, Double max)` is to generate random numbers between min and max using class Double and have `Double nextDouble()` returns the next random number as a Double class

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean because each object pulls from a different `vector` of pre-generated random numbers, OP is protected from that.

Comment: thanks for all the help guys, i really appreciated it. ima head to bed and tackle this again tomorrow. feel free to add anything you think might help and ill catch it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
Random::Random(Double min, Double max)
```

the best you can do is

```
Random::Random(Double min, Double max)
{
    fillVect(min.toDouble(), max.toDouble());
}
```

and discard the notion of `void Random::fillVect(Double min, Double max)` as redundant. But if you must implement it, then

```
Random::Random(Double min, Double max)
{
    fillVect(min, max);
}

void Random::fillVect(Double min, Double max) {
    vectx.clear();
    currIndex = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Int_b; ++i)
    {
        double r = (((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX * (max.toDouble() - min)) + min.toDouble());
        vectx.push_back(r);
    }
    shuffle();
}
```

But do note that this is idiotic. Any changes made to the `fillVect` algorithm must be made in two places, and this opens up whole families of possible bugs. Say you change one and forget to change the other. Or you find a bug and only fix it only in one. Or because of a typo you only have a bug in one. Duplicated code wastes time writing, debugging, and maintaining. And for what? So you call `toDouble` in a different place (and possibly many more times since now it's in a `for` loop. Read up on "loop hoisting" to solve that)?

For `Double nextDouble();` take advantage of `Double::Double(double d)`.

Answer (score -3):

Why repeating yourself when a simple cast can do the job ?
For example you could say :

```
fillVect( min.toDouble(), max.toDouble() )
```

Min and max are of Double type.

Comment: I doubt `Double` will cast to `double` particularly well. Almost certainly have very different memory layouts. Best to hold off on answering questions like this before OP defines the missing data types.